# why is ssh ignoring user config file

Tags: ssh

ssh is not reading from user configuration file first, but from system wide config.
this is my ssh verbose trace (while using local user, not root):

```
-bash-4.1$ ssh -v srg-b@github.com
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/html/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/www/html/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /var/www/html/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/www/html/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/www/html/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

therefore, it can't locate my keys, whose location is specified in local config. why is ssh ignoring local config file, located in `~/.ssh/config` ? The file has rwe rule 600 . I tried mod 400 as well, but to no avail.

Comment: You say the config is in `~/.ssh/config`, but tell us the full path?  Is it `/var/www/html/.ssh/config`, because that seems to be the path SSH is looking.  What account is being used to ssh?

Comment: It's probably the www-data user from an Apache or nginx install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the *owner* of ~/.ssh/config matches the username you are logged in with.  From your capture above it looks like you are logged in as `www-data` so you should do a `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/.ssh/config` from a root shell.

Please note if you have Apache pointed to `/var/www/html` it's an **EXTREMELY BAD THING** to have your SSH keys anywhere where there is a possibility Apache could touch them, as a simple misconfiguration or PHP app exploit/misconfiguration can reveal your keys to anyone who can access Apache.  You should change the home directory of the `www-data` user to something outside of any directory Apache can access.  You can do this by manually creating a directory elsewhere (e.g. `/etc/systemhome/www-data` or make a `/home/www-data`) editing the `www-data` entry for `/etc/passwd`, you would need to logout and back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: is it not `chown` instead of `chmod` ?

Comment: yep, I corrected.

Comment: I was executing ssh as a root user and I was wondered what was going on. Thanks for the answer. Comment for those who may unintentionally run the ssh/scp as the root but the ~/.ssh/config is is for a non-root user :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Host identifier in the config file and then it will use whatever is specified in your config for that Host (not the same as DNS name).
eg:

```
Host github
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem
User srg-b
```

Comment: This happened to me! I had `Host <human-readable name>` and `HostName <ip address>`, and was expecting the config to be loaded when I did `ssh <ip address>`. You must use `ssh <human-readable name>` for the config to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the `.ssh` directory is not executable by the ssh process. There's no way that `/var/www/html/.ssh` should exist in any event, so there's something fishy going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
sudo chown -R <user> ~/.ssh
```

...fixed this annoying issue for me after way too many hours trying to diagnose it -  for some reason at least one of the files in the SSH folder wasn't owned by the user who the directory belongs to.